# Какой тип у переменной x = null + null?

Tags: kotlin

Немного песни:

Какой тип, а главное почему `String` будет `x`?!

```
val x = null + null
```

Comment: судя по всему из-за [этого](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/plus.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить можно вот так:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val x = null + null
    println(x::class.simpleName)
}
```

Вывод:

```
String
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы наткнулись на довольную забавную функцию из стандартной библиотеки Kotlin. Вот ее сигнатура:

```kotlin
public operator fun String?.plus(other: Any?): String
```

Левый аргумент может принимать все строки плюс `null`, а правый — вообще любые значения Kotlin, включая `null`.

Поэтому ваш фрагмент кода аналогичен такой записи:

```kotlin
val s: String? = null
val x: String = s + null
```